# How to make an image a "hotspot" using fo:basic-link

Tags: xsl-fo

I am using below code for wrapping image under basic-link

```
<xsl:template name="bottomSection">
  <fo:block>
     <fo:basic-link color="blue" external-destination="http://www.google.com">
       <fo:external-graphic src="url('E:/images/promoAdd.jpg')"/>
     </fo:basic-link>
  </fo:block> 
</xsl:template>
```

Now, in the resulting pdf, only the very bottom edge of the image has hyperlink (it appears only when cursor is moved at the bottom of the image).

I need to display this hyperlink when cursor is moved to any part of the image.

Please let me know if I can use some other approach.

Comment: The approach looks okay to me at first sight. What FO renderer are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The `text-altitude` property can be used to make the whole image an active link. Set the value to the height of the image:

```
<fo:basic-link color="blue" external-destination="url('http://www.google.com')"
               text-altitude="75px">
  <fo:external-graphic src="url('E:/images/promoAdd.jpg')"/>
</fo:basic-link>
```

Note: I have verified that this works with the [XEP](http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html) FO processor. It does not work with FOP (`text-altitude` is [not supported](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-text-altitude)).