# Want some xsl-fo command to add social media plugin in my Rendered PDF

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to render a social media share or like plugin in my PDF which I am rendering using BI publisher jars and using xsl-fo commnads like external-graphic or something.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=537311439705217&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Dell" data-width="100" data-             layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: can you give us example of what to want ?

Comment: I need an xslt or xsl-fo command to add social media Like button or share button in XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: @MIkCode I have edited my question  please check that piece of plug in

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a method to use social media directly from the PDF. You'd have to add a hyperlink to a Web page, and handle the social media stuff on the Web page.
If all you want is a "Like" button, you can add an image, and [create a hyperlink for that image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532265/how-to-make-an-image-a-hotspot-using-fobasic-link).

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very good approach ...I tried this out and it's working fine. I have used it already before ... as part of this question post I was trying to find a way to write some java script like how we can write in php or any web application code.